# AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat error in Xamarin Forms Android Build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I had created a new Xamarin Forms project (Sept 2017), but when got around to running / building the droid platform I am getting this build error -

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat; (XYZ.Droid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In packages, update the Xamarin.Android.Support packages to the latest version.

[image]